# Spanish word for "baking soda" (regional)

Tags: traducción, vocabulario, diferencias-regionales

I was talking with a friend who lives in the Carribbean and I remember getting stuck on the word "baking soda" as in "Baking soda is a useful thing to have in the house."

[Google translate](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=es&text=baking%20soda) has given me: **bicarbonato de sodio**.  Is there another less technical translation?

I can imagine this being regional.  When I lived in Puerto Rico, we often got away with saying the English word, just "Dame el *baking soda*."  Certainly, the box was in English.

Example: What is "baking soda" called in a Mexican grocery store?

Comment: Bicarbonato de sodio, bicarbonato sódico, bicarbonato de sosa o simplemente bicarbonato.

Answer (score 7):

In Spain it is sold as *bicarbonato sódico*:

[image: bicarbonato sódico]

Usually people just call it *bicarbonato* because that's the only type of bicarbonate you're ever going to talk about (unless you are a chemist).

Another user wrote a now-deleted answer saying that in Costa Rica they call it *bicarbonato* too:

> As a native Spanish speaker from Costa Rica, when people refer to "baking soda", they just say *bicarbonato*, and it is inferred that the person is referring to *bicarbonato de sodio*:
>
> > *Voy a ir a la tienda a comprar bicarbonato*.

Comment: Nice answer @walen . I learned something new today.